# Creating a who's online from Laravel framework (Question)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks

I'm not sure whether I've done my idea, I want to create a user page online using Laravel Framework, I'm wondering if the method I used to introduce users into the database is correct and so removed after if the time exceeds the limit.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Automatism {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        DB::table('users_online')->updateOrInsert(
          ['user-ip' => \Request::getClientIp(true)],
          [
            'user-viewing-url' => Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri(),
            'user-ip' => \Request::getClientIp(true),
            'timestamps' => now()
          ]
        );

        DB::table('users_online')->where('timestamps', '<', 'now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE')->delete();
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then next to this code I wanted to do the same for users who have been on the site within 24 hours.

Comment: i would save the users_online by user-id and make that unique. then don't bother deleting rows but just update it after every request. 
now you can just query all rows that have a timestamp between now and 5 min ago or now and 24 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

I made a middleware to track user activity once, here is it maybe it can gives you ideas:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        if(Auth::check()) {
            Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true, Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
            $this->storeDailyUserActivity();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    public function storeDailyUserActivity(){
        $daily_active_user = [];
        if(Cache::has('daily_active_user')){
            $daily_active_user = Cache::get('daily_active_user');
            if(!is_array($daily_active_user)){
                Cache::forget('daily_active_user');
                $this->storeDailyUserActivity();
                return;
            }
            $daily_active_user['cache_old_date'] = $daily_active_user['cache_date'] ?? 'err_no_cache_date'; //debug only
        }
        $daily_active_user[Auth::user()->id] = Carbon::now();
        $daily_active_user['cache_date'] = Carbon::now()->toTimeString() . ' - ' . $this->request->url(); //debug only
        Cache::forever('daily_active_user', $daily_active_user);
    }
```

- It uses Cache to prevent execute DB query on every request (if you really need to save this to your DB, you'll need to adapt). Note: You'll need a cache driver that support cache keys (check Laravel doc).
- It stores a unique cache key per user, so later in your code, you can check on this same key for a specific user (eg: if this user was active in the last 5 minutes)
- It also stores all users last activity date in an array. So you can loop on it, find users, and when they were active last time (eg: display all user with activity in the last 2h).
- It's kind of an old snippet and could be improved. Helpers to check on those cache values (eg: `isUserActiveInLastMinutes($minutes = 5)`) can then easily be made.

In the case you really need to save it to your DB, I'd do:

- add a `last_activity` timestamp column on users (or a oneToOne relation between users table and user_activity table eg)
- update this last_activity on every user request (I would recommend to at least use a 5minute cache to prevent add a DB query on every user request)
- you can then eloquent query "all users with last_activity > Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)"